# NPM not ignoring folders specified in gitignore

Tags: git, github, npm

I have created a github repository which was committed with the initial .gitignore and set to the defaults of a visual studio project.

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
obj/
```

I pulled the project from Github, proceeded to create a visual studio solution in the folder (Typescript), added some TS files and built the project. In the folder was also an NPM package json with all the version information etc...

```
npm init
```

The bin and obj folders were created after the build and ignored by GIT as expected. I proceeded to make the first commit to github

```
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git push origin master
```

On github everything seems fine. There are no bin or obj folders to be seen and everything is up to date. 
So I then proceeded to publish the folder onto NPM. I went into the folder directory and typed

```
npm publish
```

It successfully published the project to NPM.

In a separate project I added my new npm registry to the dependencies and did an update:

```
npm update
```

I checked the node_modules folder and found the project from github. However - it included the bin and obj folders. Why did it include these? They are not on github and were specified in the gitignore file - so why does NPM keep adding them? I've tried clearing the cache, and  re-pushing / re-publishing on both github and npm without any success.

Comment: Do you have an `.npmignore` file?

Comment: Hi Chris. No I don't - I thought that it was optional?

Comment: It is optional, but [it overrides `.gitignore` if it's present](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package). Is your `.gitignore` file in the root of your project?

Comment: Yes the gitignore file is in the root and there is no npmignore file present